# Travis-ci don't update my firebase hosting website after successful build I use angular (2-4)

Tags: angular, firebase, github, travis-ci, firebase-hosting

**I have added FIREBASE_TOKEN on Travis that I generate from firebase login:ci**

### i have this error on travis only

[image]

### .travis.yml

```
#.travis.yml

language: node_js
node_js:
  - "7"

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_script:
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
  - npm install -g @angular/cli

script:
  - ng build --prod

after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN

notifications:
  email:
    on_failure: change
    on_success: change
```

#### And I am not sure but this is my git ignore file from angular CLI

the /dist folder is not pushed on GitHub repo because angular CLI default gitignore, can I uncomment the dist from git ignore file ??

### .gitignore

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add inside .travis.yml this code because I use alias for my project

```
after_success:
  - firebase use --add my-alias
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```